# Неправильная сортировка времени и даты

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, время

Пробую отсортировать значения даты от меньшего к большему, ну и чтобы время внутри было по порядку от меньшего к большему. А получается каша.

```
df = pd.read_csv('min.csv')
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Value']

def change(x):
    x=x.replace(':','').replace('/','')
    return int(x)

df['num_date']=df.Date.apply(change)
df['num_time']=df.Time.apply(change)


df=df.sort_values(['num_date','num_time'])
df=df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

[Данные такие](http://file.sampo.ru/zw774s/):

```
4/13/2017   7:11:00     4351
4/13/2017   6:23:00     500
4/13/2017   6:21:00     100
4/13/2017   6:14:00     400
4/13/2017   6:11:00     100
4/13/2017   4:18:00     500
4/13/2017   4:17:00     156
4/13/2017   4:07:00     140
4/13/2017   4:01:00     209
4/12/2017   20:00:00    905
4/12/2017   19:59:00    3500
4/12/2017   19:58:00    700
4/12/2017   19:55:00    700
4/12/2017   19:53:00    100
4/12/2017   19:50:00    100
4/12/2017   19:46:00    200
4/12/2017   19:44:00    271
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .assign(x=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"] + " " + df["Time"]))
       .sort_values("x")
       .drop(columns="x"))
```

---

результат:

```
In [49]: res
Out[49]:
           Date      Time  Value
1815  4/10/2017  12:53:00  59092
1814  4/10/2017  12:54:00  55871
1813  4/10/2017  12:55:00  22805
1812  4/10/2017  12:56:00  61095
1811  4/10/2017  12:57:00  15093
...         ...       ...    ...
4     4/13/2017  19:28:00    850
3     4/13/2017  19:30:00    883
2     4/13/2017  19:43:00    100
1     4/13/2017  19:44:00    100
0     4/13/2017  19:58:00    100

[1816 rows x 3 columns]
```